# Is it possible to set the width of an element based on the height of the parent element? How to do this?

Tags: html, css

I'm researching a few things about CSS and I had that doubt. I searched about it in other posts on the web, but i don't find yet.

If i have some `img` with height equals 80% of its parent `div` (its width will also be the same), how can i set the `input`'s width to fill in the remaining space.

The code snippet might look like the one below:

```css
.forms {
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    height: 36px; /*This height change for different devices*/
    padding: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#inputSearch {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

#imgSearch {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  height: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="forms">
   <input id="inputSearch" type="text">
   <img id="imgSearch" src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/search-icon-png-21.png">
</div>
```

In my case, i can not change the parent `div` attributes, like display, because i am using a project pattern. There are other elements next to parent `div`. Hence, i want to change only the children attributes.

I would appreciate if someone guide me about that.

Comment: Can you give an example on CodePen or something as to what your current situation is and what you are looking for specifically with a screenshot or different image. Because recreating this on CodePen as is doesn't really give me any insight as to what the problem is.

Comment: Sure! I just did that.

Comment: I’d simply position the image absolute, and have the input field go over the full width underneath it, with an appropriate padding-right so that the input field content does not go under the image …

Comment: @misorude Yeah, I did this earlier, but I still can not specify the size of this padding-right. I need to use the width of the image (or height of the parent div) as a parameter shape.

Comment: @Rimble, I did that you was say.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a possible solution if i understood right the problem.
Try this using flex properties :

```
#parent{
display : flex;
//optional alignment
align-items: center;
}
#inputSearch{
flex-grow: 1;
}
#imgSearch{
width: 80%;
height: 80%;
}
```

Comment: I cant change the parent's atributtes because i am using a project pattern. Therefore, i need to keep the parent's display as block. There are other elements next the parent div, i only can change the children atributtes. Even so, thank you for help!